# While deriving the electric field around a infinitely long wire why do we consider a cylinder as an Gaussian plane?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law

While deriving the electric field around a infinitely long wire why do we consider a cylinder as an Gaussian plane. My teacher said that this is the only figure from any point of it we can draw a perpendicular which is basic conditions of a equipotential surface.  Please explain the reasoning!

Comment: There is a difference between a surface and a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying Gauss' law, we want to make as many choices as possible that simplify the calculation of $\mathbf{E}$. Letting $S$ be the Gaussian surface with unit normal vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ and area $A$, here are some choices that we want to make:

1. We want to choose a surface at which $\mathbf{E \cdot \hat{n}}$ is constant (or varies in a simple way). 
   That way, the law reads 
   $$ \int_{S} \mathbf{E \cdot \hat{n}} \ dS = A(\mathbf{E \cdot \hat{n}}) = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
   $$ \mathbf{E \cdot \hat{n}} = \frac{Q_{enc}}{A \epsilon_0} $$
   This is a great simplification, as now there are no more surface integrals to do.
2. We want $\mathbf{E}$ to be parallel to $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$, because then $\mathbf{E \cdot \hat{n}} = \vert \mathbf{E} \vert$. 
   where $S$ is the surface over which we integrate. Then, following the expression above, we have
   $$ \vert \mathbf{E} \vert = \frac{Q_{enc}}{A \epsilon_0} $$
   and finally 
   $$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{Q_{enc}}{A \epsilon_0} \mathbf{\hat{n}} $$
   as $\mathbf{E}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$.

The upshot of all of this is that if we choose $S$ such that the following conditions are met, we can get an *exact* expression for the electric field.

With this in mind, let us consider the case of an infinite line of charge, along the $z$-axis WLOG. Let us consider cylindrical coordinates.

Regardless of how we move parallel to the line, the line will look the same, so the electric field can have no dependence on $z$. Moreover, the line looks the same if we travel in a circle in a plane perpendicular to the line centered at a point on the $z$-axis, so the electric field is independent of $\theta$. We also see that the electric field should not have any $z$-component at any point, as this would accelerate a charged particle indefinitely in the $z$-direction, violating the conservation of energy. For similar reasons, the electric field cannot have any $\theta$-component. From the above physical consideration, the electric field has only an $r$-component, dependent on $r$ alone, so we can write $\mathbf{E} = E(r) \mathbf{\hat{r}}$.

Now, a cylinder of radius $r_0$ has normal vector $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ at each point $(\mathbf{r}, z)$ (with $\vert \mathbf{r} \vert = r_0$). Therefore, at every point on the cylinder, $\mathbf{E} \propto \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{\hat{r}}$. Moreover, $\mathbf{E \cdot \hat{n}} = E(r_0) (\mathbf{\hat{r} \cdot \hat{r}}) = E(r_0)$. Therefore, both conditions $1$ and $2$ are satisfied for a cylinder! This is why we use the Gaussian cylinder; it satisfies both conditions which greatly simplify our application of Gauss' law.

For completeness, let me finish the derivation, and note how simple it is! If the cylinder has height $l$ and the line has linear density $\lambda$, we may therefore write *immediately* that

$$ E(r_0) = \frac{Q_{enc}}{2\pi \epsilon_0 r_0 l} = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi \epsilon_0 r_0} $$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Because the charge distribution has cylindrical symmetry, the field will also be cylindrically symmetric.  Thus, the flux through a Gaussian cylinder of radius $r$ and length $\ell$ coaxial with your wire will be constant on the surface of that cylinder so that $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec S= \vert \vec E(r)\vert 2\pi r \ell$ will allow you to deduce $\vert \vec E(r)\vert $ using Gauss’ law and the charge enclosed by your cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

If we try to think of the direction of electrostatic field of the infinite wire (because unless you find it, you have to think about it), so if the wire is straight vertical wire then its electrostatic field cannot point in any arbitrary direction, since we know that two electric field lines can't intersect each other because this would result into two directions of electric field at a point. 
Also, for the whole wire the electrostatic field should be identical in direction with any part of it, because the wire is uniformly charged.
Therefore we take the surface to be cylindrical because this is the only choice which is left and which satisfies all the conditions.